# driving distance between two places in php is not working

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

I have use the code given below to get the latitude and longitude of a place for calculating driving distance between two places.

```
function get_coordinates($city, $street, $province)
{
$address = urlencode($city.','.$street.','.$province);
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=Poland";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response_a = json_decode($response);
$status = $response_a->status;
if ( $status == 'ZERO_RESULTS' )
{
    return FALSE;
}
else
{
    $return = array('lat' => $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lat, 'long' => $long = $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lng);
   return $return;
}
```

}

I am not get it. It shows an empty array. when echo $status I am getting 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT'.
This code is working perfectly in godaddy server . Iam getting these error when i have changed it into network solutions server.
How can solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` means you have exhausted the use of API for the day.

Here is the explanation:

> 2,500 free requests per day, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.
>
> 50 requests per second, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.

*[Google Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits)*

You can generate few API keys as per your requirement and switch them when exhausted.

[*Generate API Key from Google Console*](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)

Hope this helps!

Comment: But it is working in another server with the same api

Comment: That's because of IP address. Google tracks API limit through IP. Your local IP is different than that of server. You have exhausted API usage on local and server still has usage left.

Comment: one is our company server which is godaddy  and another is of client which is network solution. thia is working in godaddy.but not in network solution.

Comment: Yes that's what i meant. Godaddy server has different IP and your network solution has different IP.

Comment: i have tried many times in godaddy. still working in that.but in network solution i just started testing.

Comment: Try passing API Key in the request.

Comment: i am using this link  to fetch latitude and longitude http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=Poland.i am not using any api here. I have a little knowledge in this.

Comment: Sample with key parameter `https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=Poland&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Comment: API keys are now required, and when used allow the quota to be that for your google account, not the IP address.  Enabling billing on the key allows a larger free quota as well.